# Custom DatagridTemplateColumn button - Bind button content to custom column property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I want to create a custom datagridcolumn with a button. I want it reusable, so I don't want to define the text of the button in the template, but in a dependency property of the column (ButtonText as string).

Here is the code I have so far (not working)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Class="RafColumnButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d"  CanUserResize="False">

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:RafColumnButton}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I think it has something to do with datacontext, but I'm a debutant in wpf.

EDIT :here is the rafcolumnButton codebehind for the dependency property

```
Public Property ButtonText As String
    Get
        Return GetValue(ButtonTextProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly ButtonTextProperty As DependencyProperty =
                       DependencyProperty.Register(NameOf(ButtonText),
                       GetType(String), GetType(RafColumnButton),
                       New PropertyMetadata(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext` of the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` is the the current data item.

If the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` contains data items that have a property `ButtonText`, then the following binding will work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**Remarks**
You can't bind to `DataGridTemplateColumn` or `DataGridColumn` in general. This is because `DataGridColumn` doesn't derive from `Visual` and therefore cannot be part of the visual tree. Only types that derive from abstract class `Visual` like `UIElement` can be part of the visual tree. Only types that derive from `FrameworkElement` can be part of the logical tree. See [Microsoft Docs: Trees in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/trees-in-wpf?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

`DataGridColumn` can be viewed as placeholder for the actual controls that makeup the column and cells.

Comment: Yes I know. I have other column (image) which work like that. But I want to bind on the ButtonText property of the datagridcolumn itself (it's a custom dependency property of type text) i will edit my question with that.

Comment: See my answer's remarks. This should clarify some things.

Comment: I'm really sad. I created the property on the datagrid, and it works, but that mean that I will be able to use that type fo column only once by datagrid. If there is another way...

Comment: Please come again. You've created the `ButtonText` property on a custom `DataGrid`? You can of course bind to the parent `DataGrid`. Is this what you want? I understood that this property is defined on a custom `DataGridColumn`.

Comment: No, I wanted the property on the column itself. But as you suggested, I tried (just for the try) to create it on the datagrid and it works. But that's not what I wanted, because, With this, I can just have one column of this type in a datagrid (or more, but with same text). Another solution that is possible is to create a readonly property on the datasource itself, with the text of the button. But I don't really like that solution.

Comment: I see. I thought I misunderstood you. But your conclusions are absolutely correct. The `DataGridColumn` is just a place holder for the column type to render. If you want max layout flexibility you choose `DataGridTemplateColumn`. The data itself is not provided by this layout column objects. It's the data model that provides the data. Hence your data should move to the data model. I definitely wouldn't call such a property "ButtonText"  as it's too UI related. I would call it e.g. "Tag", something more general. Generally all data you need to display in a cell should come from the data model.